# How to make onchange dropdown option-url to open in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
<option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
<option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
<option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
<option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
<option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this code and i want to open by click the selected in my page! not open another! thank you!

Comment: What was wrong with the code you had before? Change `window.open` to `location.href`.

Comment: What's wrong? Your code is working for me,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this :

```
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_self');
};
```

**window.open(URL,name,specs,replace):
where name:**

```
_blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
_self - URL replaces the current page
_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)
```

**[DEMO Link](http://jsbin.com/uGEBEce/1)**

Answer (score 3):

Add second parameter `_self`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="menu1" id="menu1">
        <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
        <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
        <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
        <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
        <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
     urlmenu.onchange = function() {
          window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_self');
     };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check '_top' is not working for me. I guess it is '_self' as per http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Interesting!!! '_top' is not working in 'Edit' mode in JsBin but working in 'View' mode.

Answer (score 0):

The code you had before worked fine:

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1');
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
    location.href = $("#menu1 option:selected").val();
};
```

Comment: It was working, but it was creating the link in an another page! i wnated in my page!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it in javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleChange() {
            var arr = document.getElementById( 'menu1' ) ;
            window.location = arr.value ;
        } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="menu1" id="menu1" onchange="handleChange()">
            <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
            <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
            <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
            <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
            <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
        </select>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use no extra JavaScript code. Use only HTML select option with onchange attributes

Use this onchange attributes on your select option

```
onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
```

Complete Select option menu

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select an Item</option>
<option value="Member.html">Member Report</option>
<option value="Account.html">Account Statement</option>
<option value="Employee.html">Employee Report</option>
<option value="Branch.html">Branch Report</option>
<option value="Area">Area Report</option>
<option value="Designation.html">Designation Report</option>
```

Hope it better solution for you!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.location.href(document.getElementById("menu1").value);
};
```

Change the `window.open` to `window.location` if you want to open the link in the current window. `window.open` opens the link in a new tab!

However, the jQuery code worked fine!

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1');
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.location.href = $("#menu1 option:selected").val();
};
```

Comment: It's still opening in a new window!

Comment: ```window.location``` and ```window.location.href``` are *read-only* properties, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).  While assigning a value to ```window.location.href``` technically *works*, it may cause adverse behavior in the future if this is ever changed.  Better to use the ```open``` method since the behavior is known.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function getValue(value){ 
var href = value; 
 if (href) window.open(href,"_self");
}
</script>
<select name="menu1" id="menu1" onchange="getValue(this.value);">
  <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
  <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
  <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
  <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
  <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing this:

```
window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
```

with this:

```
window .location.href = $("#menu1 option:selected").val();
```